# Azure databricks and Python virtual enviroment

Tags: python, azure, virtualenv, databricks, azure-databricks

Since 2020 Azure databricks no longer supports moving virtual environments between notebooks with

```
%conda env export
%conda env update
```

What would be a good workaround? Do I just  install libraries that I need into every notebook (maybe with requirements file)?

Comment: If you are using Interactive notebooks, then install it once in your all-purpose cluster.

Comment: If it's a JOB, then deploy it using dbx (requirements.txt) or manually add it once in Workflow component

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
You can use `%pip install -r /dbfs/requirements.txt`.

Check out: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries#use-a-requirements-file-to-install-libraries`